# Extensions are disabled in `php.ini` and they still show up on `phpinfo.php`... why?

Tags: homebrew, apache, mysql, php

So, I finally decide it to switch from windows to Mac after 20 years, and I love it! I have so many questions...
I've installed apache, php, mysql, imagemagick using `homebrew` and I have a couple of questions...

In `httpd.conf`, im loading the PHP module like so:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

My `php.ini` is here:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
```

When I look at the `phpinfo.php` I see all these extensions (or modules) that are enabled:

[image]
But, when I look at the `php.ini` file, I see that those extensions are disabled

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
```

Don't get me wrong, everything works perfectly, but i'm one of those people that likes to understand how it works...

Any reasons why my extensions are disabled in `php.ini` and they still show up on `phpinfo.php`?

**EDITED**

[image]

Comment: Those are the compile options that php is able to *handle*.  cURL support is *enabled* not the cURL module itself.  If you want to see the loaded modules, go to the command line and type `php -m`

Comment: @Allan So, if I uncomment `extension=curl` in `php.ini`, for example, what does it do? I type `php -m` and I see a list and in the list I see `curl` (see picture in edited post).

Comment: Now *that* says cURL module is loaded.  (You could also use `php -m | grep curl`.  This means you're not editing the correct ini file and/or not restarting php after making the change.

Comment: @Allan That's why I've asked the question, because it's so strange. I did some research and found no other `.ini` file. On `phpinfo.php`, it's pointing to the correct `ini` file. So, I'm thinking that maybe some modules are loaded by default...

Comment: macOS ships with an out of date version of PHP.  Did you try to upgrade it?  Usually folks do this via Homebrew or MacPorts.  If you did, then you have two different versions of php and a different ini file.

Comment: @Allan. That is exactly what I did. I upgraded php using `homebrew`.

Comment: Then there is another php.ini being loaded.  I don't run XAMP on a Mac as it introduces too much complexity and there are virtually no Mac web servers from hosting companies. So I much prefer to light up a VM (like FreeBSD) and load my AMP stack there.  It's virtually identical to my production environment. So, long story short, you've got to find that ini file, unfortunately, I don't know where it is off the top of my head.

Comment: @Allan I did a research and found only 2 `ini` files: `php.ini` and apple's default `php.ini.default`. And both have all the modules commented. I'll continued researching this issue. Maybe there is a default folder with and everything found on that folder is loaded by default.

Answer (score 1):

The enabled extensions are listed in a different section of phpinfo.